# Hiding Hour / Minute Options for Time/Date Column in forms

Tags: 2007, jquery, form, date-time

SharePoint 2007 environment.

If I wanted to limited the options in the hour column (10 - 17 hrs) and time intervals in the mins slot (30 mins only), what's the best way to achieve this.  I'm thinking that a quick and dirty fashion would be to limited the returned options in the form once the page has rendered sing jQuery but I'm not sure where I'd start.

Ideas appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Create 4 fields:

1. NewDate as Date only
2. FixedHr as Number limited to max-min of 10-17
3. FixedMin (Boolean or Yes/No)
4. Calculated Field to Concatenate the 3 fields above.  Something like: =Concatenate(NewDate, FixedHr, ":", FixedMin)